# How can I get the actual payload that the phone downloads when it installs my app from the app store?

Tags: app-store, reverse-engineering, jailbreak

I want to inspect the payload to answer questions like, is the whole __TEXT segment encrypted or just the __text section? The furthest I've gotten is, with a jailbroken phone, disabling SSL and then sniffing the download. However, that requires me to be on wi-fi, and on wi-fi, it downloads a pre-thinned version of the app that's larger. This is OK, except that I want to see what a fully thinned version looks like and see how close it is to the 100 MB WWAN limit. When I do `find / -name '*.ipa'`, I don't find the app. So I guess it's immediately decompressing the .ipa upon download and then deleting it? But in that case, I don't know how to intercept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an iOS app .ipa (zipped bundle) file, just download the app from the App Store using iTunes on a Mac.

Added: Or download with Apple Configurator 2 on a Mac.

It might be easier on a Mac to sniff the ipa file read when installing an app from macOS iTunes to an iOS device (during a Sync).

Comment: The issue is that this could yield a different result than if I download it on WWAN on the phone

Comment: Correction: this is fine as long as you run `ipatool` to thin it afterwards I think